# PushApps - iOS notifications don't arrive after uploading the p12 file

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushapps

I've followed the [iOS getting started](https://wiki.pushapps.mobi/display/PUSHAPPS/iOS+Getting+Started) tutorial here, registered my device but the notifications don't seem to arrive. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to:

1. Check the exact reason in the [statistics page](https://wiki.pushapps.mobi/display/PUSHAPPS/Statistics) of that notification
2. Did you compile the app with the correct provision profile? In order to test with production certificate, you'll need to compile the app with AdHoc provision profile.
3. For easier debugging, please add our error delegation method as shown in our wiki [here](https://wiki.pushapps.mobi/display/PUSHAPPS/PushApps+Delegation#PushAppsDelegation-pushRegFailed.)

Comment: Guess what, Xcode provisioning profile was set "automatic" but did not figure out the correct provisioning profile. 

I used `security cms -D -i /path/to/the.app/embedded.mobileprovision` to realize that.